# Angular2 xlink:href url() issue

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have d3.js chart, which has rounded text on  sectors end

first it draws arcs

```html
//Draw the arcs themselves
svg.selectAll(".monthArc")
 .data(pie(monthData))
        .enter().append("path")
 .attr("class", "monthArc")
 .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "monthArc_"+i; }) //Give each slice a unique ID
 .attr("d", arc);
```

then binds text to it

```html
//Append the month names within the arcs
svg.selectAll(".monthText")
 .data(monthData)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
 .attr("class", "monthText")
 .attr("x", 5)   //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
 .attr("dy", 18) //Move the text down  
        .append("textPath")
 .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#monthArc_"+i;})
 .text(function(d){return d.month;});
```

Result is something like that

[image]

It works good in normal situations, but refuses to work inside angular2 environment.

I do not have any error & warning message, inside console, texts are just not displaying

I have tried
`.attr("attr.xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#monthArc_"+i;})`

also
`.attr("attr.xlink:href",function(d,i){return "/#monthArc_"+i;})`

also
`.attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "/#monthArc_"+i;})`

but without success

I found this link - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9510 , so it's a security risk?

### Question:

### Has anyone encountered similar behavior and does anyone knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went to wrong direction :

Problem simply was wrong url

**solution:**

If you are rendering chart at address

`http://localhost:4200/test`

then your url should look something like this

`.attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "test#monthArc_"+i;})`